# Why the result from linq to viewmodel been duplicate in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Good day all,

I'm new in MVC. 
The Issue : The data repeated (duplicate). 
Suppose diffrent data populate but it appear same record. 
it took last record and shows all records same (duplicate).
i dont know where is my mistake.

i checked 'Qdata' populate correct data. but when go to view model been duplicate.

**Controller**

```
List<ApprovalVM> SmPSetVM = new List<ApprovalVM>();
ApprovalVM setVM = new ApprovalVM();

var Qdata = (from u in db.SSM_RegisSet
         join c in db.SSM_LinkRegisUpload on u.PKRegisId equals c.FKRegisId
         join v in db.SSM_UploadData on c.FKUpDid equals v.UplId
         join b in db.SSM_User on u.FKUserId equals b.PK_Uid
         join g in db.SSM_Department on b.FK_DepartId equals g.PK_DeptId
         join t in db.SSM_Team on b.FK_TeamId equals t.PK_TeamId
         join k in db.SSM_GM on b.FK_GMId equals k.PK_GM_id
         //where v.SN_NO == da
         //orderby u.AutoEC_id
         select new
         {
             v.PO_NO,
             v.SN_NO,
             v.Exp_NO,
             v.Model,
             v.PlanDate,
             v.Holder_Id,
             ids = "I000" + u.PKRegisId,
             c.PKLinkId,
             g.HODName,
             b.PK_Uid,
             b.UserName,
             t.PK_TeamId,
             t.TeamLeaderName,
             k.GMName
         }).ToList().OrderByDescending(v=>v.PKLinkId);

foreach (var item in Qdata)//.Where(x => x.SN_NO == da))
{
    setVM.PO_NO = item.PO_NO;
    setVM.SN_NO = item.SN_NO;
    setVM.Exp_NO = item.Exp_NO;
    setVM.Model = item.Model;
    setVM.PlanDate = item.PlanDate;
    setVM.Holder_Id = item.Holder_Id;
    setVM.POSNId = item.ids;
    setVM.PKLinkId = item.PKLinkId;
    setVM.PK_TeamId = item.PK_TeamId;
    setVM.HODName = item.HODName;
    setVM.PK_Uid = item.PK_Uid;
    setVM.UserName = item.UserName;
    setVM.TeamLeaderName = item.TeamLeaderName;
    setVM.GMName = item.GMName;
    SmPSetVM.Add(setVM);
}
return View(SmPSetVM);
```

**View Model**

```
public class ApprovalVM
{
    // User
    public int PK_Uid { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    // Team Leader
    public int PK_TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string TeamLeaderName { get; set; }

    // GM Name
    public int PK_GM_id { get; set; }
    public string GMName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> GMIsVisible { get; set; }

    //Department
    public int PK_DeptId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string HODName { get; set; }

    //Upload Data
    public int UplId { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "PO No")]
    public string PO_NO { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "S/N")]
    public string SN_NO { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Exp No")]
    public string Exp_NO { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string PlanDate { get; set; }
    public string Holder_Id { get; set; }

    // Regis Id
    public string POSNId { get; set; }

    //Link 
    public int PKLinkId { get; set; }

    // List of Approval
    //public List<ApprovalVM> ListApproval { get; set; } 

}
```

**View**

```
 <div class="col-lg-11">
        <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="IntTrntbl">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        No
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.POSNId)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PO_NO)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SN_NO)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Exp_NO)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlanDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Holder_Id)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PKLinkId)
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @{int a = 1;}
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @(a++)
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:10%">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.POSNId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PO_NO)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SN_NO)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Exp_NO)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlanDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holder_Id)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PKLinkId)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you don't instantiate a new setVM in foreach loop. You should move the initialization of setVM object(ApprovalVM setVM = new ApprovalVM();) in foreach loop.
In each iteration you modify the same object and add it to your list.

Comment: tq ..i want keep out side foreach due to i have partial view.
 **ViewModel**

'public List<ApprovalVM> ListApproval { get; set; }'
so can view at partial view

Comment: @user3538475 i didn't understand the requirement from your last comment. Coud you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the same object in every iteration of the loop. You initialize the `setVM` once and then add it to the list many times. Therefore the list contains multiple entries of the same item. As you update the object in the foreach then all references that point to that item reference the new value.

Instantiate a new item in each iteration:

```
foreach (var item in Qdata)//.Where(x => x.SN_NO == da))
{
    setVM = new ApprovalVM();
    setVM.PO_NO = item.PO_NO;
    setVM.SN_NO = item.SN_NO;
    setVM.Exp_NO = item.Exp_NO;
    setVM.Model = item.Model;
    setVM.PlanDate = item.PlanDate;
    setVM.Holder_Id = item.Holder_Id;
    setVM.POSNId = item.ids;
    setVM.PKLinkId = item.PKLinkId;
    setVM.PK_TeamId = item.PK_TeamId;
    setVM.HODName = item.HODName;
    setVM.PK_Uid = item.PK_Uid;
    setVM.UserName = item.UserName;
    setVM.TeamLeaderName = item.TeamLeaderName;
    setVM.GMName = item.GMName;
    SmPSetVM.Add(setVM);
}
```

But if already using linq then you can improve and project this class in the query (and use the object initializer syntax):

```
return View((from u in db.SSM_RegisSet
             join c in db.SSM_LinkRegisUpload on u.PKRegisId equals c.FKRegisId
             join v in db.SSM_UploadData on c.FKUpDid equals v.UplId
             join b in db.SSM_User on u.FKUserId equals b.PK_Uid
             join g in db.SSM_Department on b.FK_DepartId equals g.PK_DeptId
             join t in db.SSM_Team on b.FK_TeamId equals t.PK_TeamId
             join k in db.SSM_GM on b.FK_GMId equals k.PK_GM_id
             //where v.SN_NO == da
             //orderby u.AutoEC_id
             select new ApprovalVM {
                 PO_NO  = v.PO_NO,
                 //And so on
             }).OrderByDescending(v=>v.PKLinkId).ToList());
```

And last, if using EF then read into [Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx). Will make joins much simpler.